# Is static final (eager) singleton thread safe in java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

If I create a singleton object using `static final`, then will it be thread safe? Here is the example code.

```
public class StaticSingleton {
    private static final StaticSingleton instance = new StaticSingleton();

    private StaticSingleton() {
    }

    public static StaticSingleton GetInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make the singleton object itself *thread-safe* if that's what you mean, just the initialisation (unless you do something dodgy within).

Comment: Also, it is apparently very fast, when comparing with all other non-static non-final solutions: http://literatejava.com/jvm/fastest-threadsafe-singleton-jvm/

Answer (score 0):

Yea, That's eager as you said and also thread safe. take a look in this example:

```
classFoo {
    private static class HelperHolder{
        public static final Helper helper= new Helper();
    }

    public static Helper getHelper() {
        return HelperHolder.helper;
    }
}
```

This is not eager so our helper object will be created only when you will need him (inner classes are not loaded until they are referenced) - lazy :)

Comment: Usually pointless as you probably aren't going to initialise `Foo` without almost immediately calling `getHelper`, not unless `Foo` is a big mess of a class.